# Problema con Validar version de app

Tags: android, android-studio, control-de-versiones, jsoup

Buenos días

Estoy desarrollando una app, solo que estoy tratando de hacer una validación de la versión de la app que se tiene instala con la versión que se tiene en el playstore

Estoy utilizado este código

```
newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + package_name + "&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get()
                .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                .first()
                .ownText();
```

solo que me da el sieguiente error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Comment: Hola Hugo, es importante indicar que estas usando Jsoup para realizar la conección.

Comment: ahh perdon, se me paso ese dato

Comment: Si me podras ayudar Jorgeys, u orientas como comparo la version que tengo instalada en mi movil con la version del play store?

Comment: Con gusto, pero pláticame para que deseas realizar esta comparación?

Comment: si lo que deseo es que los usuario actualicen la aplicación

Comment: Los usuarios actualizan la aplicación si es que existe un update, en la mayoría de los casos esto es automático. ¿Cual es la diferencia con lo que deseas realizar?

Comment: Bueno lo que pasa es que yo estoy subiendo apk al play store, pero no se por que razon en los moviles de los usuarios no se les actualiza la app

Comment: El error se debe a que Jsoup no soporta SSL, para eso necesitas el certificado, o bien hay maneras de conectarse a https pero no las recomiendo ya que es deshabilitando el certificado y afecta a todas las instancias que hagan uso de `HttpsURLConnection` aun siendo externas a la clase. Por otro lado hay una API **NO OFICIAL** que podria ser de utilidad, dejo el enlace (en ingles): https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/